# setDrawerListener crashes android app

Tags: java, android, navigation-drawer, android-spinner, android-toolbar

I am developing android app in which, i want Menudrawer and Spinner on single activity.

Code snippet:

```
public class Dashboard extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.layout_dashboard);


    // Spinner element
        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

   // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);

   // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinner1.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

   // Spinner click listener
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {


            // Showing selected spinner item
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {
            // your code here
        }

    });


   //Adding MenuDrawer...
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar); 
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();


        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) this);
}
```

I have written the above code but it crashes with the following error:

> Java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout$DrawerListener)'
>   on a null object reference at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity

Here's the layout xml file:

**layout_dashboard.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/quantityField"
        android:hint="Qunatity"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="phone"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/priceField"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:hint="Price" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5 August 2016"
        android:id="@+id/dateBtn"
        android:height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


    <Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add"
        android:id="@+id/addBtn"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please share you logcat

Comment: Show your layout_dashboard.xml file.

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/PsjZ6

Comment: please post your layout_dashboard.xml file

Comment: And change navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener((NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener) this);  to navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

Comment: posted `layout.xml` file

Comment: Where is your DrawerLayout with id drawer_layout in your layout_dashboard.xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please change your xml file to below, I have added `DrawerLayout` and `NavigationView` to your layout which was missing your layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>


<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:background="@drawable/spinner_border"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/quantityField"
    android:hint="Qunatity"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/priceField"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:hint="Price" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="5 August 2016"
    android:id="@+id/dateBtn"
    android:height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add"
    android:id="@+id/addBtn"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/button_shape"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    />


</LinearLayout>


<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:itemTextAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Showing error here: `Error parsing XML: junk after document element`

Comment: and just to be clear, are you passing the menu file `drawer.xml` which contains menu options in `navigationView` ?

Comment: Just updated the answer, actually I forgot to add an empty line so some lines of code were not visible in answer, please copy the updated answer and try again.

Comment: code works, error not coming but unable to open menudrawer dont know why :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117815/discussion-between-krunal-and-himanshu1496).

Answer (score 1):

There is no view with `android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"` in your layout with name `layout_dashboard`.

**UPD**

Seems there is misunderstanding from your side how to use `DrawerLayout`. [There is good article](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html) about that, please check and let me know if there is still any questions.

Comment: `layout_dashboard` is my xml file and it is present inside layout folder.

Comment: @Krunal Yes, but there is no view with id = drawer_layout. Post your drawer_layout